# Azure DevOps Azure CLI task with PowerShell script and parallel ForEach-Object execution: no output on failure

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-cli

In order to scale Function Apps quickly we want to be able to deploy them via IaC and then deploy a code package onto it. Unfortunately this is not possible dynamically with YAML pipelines in Azure DevOps so I had to resort to using the Azure CLI.

Below you see the PowerShell script I came up with to deploy the code into the pool of Function Apps that I deployed through Terraform before-hand. To speed things up I turned on parallel processing of the `ForEach-Object` loop since there are no dependencies between the single instances. This also works fine to a certain extent but I am having troubles due to the quirkiness of the Azure CLI. Writing non-error information to StdErr seems to be by design. This combined with some other strange behavior leads to the following scenarios:

- Running sequentially usually works flawlessly and I see any error output if a problem occurs. Also I don't need to set `powerShellErrorActionPreference: 'continue'`. This of course is slowing down the deployment significantly.
- Running in parallel fails **always** without setting `powerShellErrorActionPreference: 'continue'`. The reason for the failure is not output to the console. This seems to happen even if no real error occurs as with `continue` there is no error output to the console as well. This wouldn't be an issue if the pipeline fails in the case of a real error (which should be handled by checking the state of the `ChildJobs` - but it doesn't.

So here I am between a rock and a hard place. Does anyone see the flaw in my implementation? Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Functions deployment'
  env:
    AZURE_CORE_ONLY_SHOW_ERRORS: 'True'
    AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
    ARM_CLIENT_ID: $(AzureApplicationId)
    ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: $(AzureApplicationSecret)
    ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: $(AzureSubscriptionId)
    ARM_TENANT_ID: $(AzureTenantId)
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'MySubscription'
    scriptType: 'pscore'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      Write-Output -InputObject "INFO: Get Function App names"          
      $appNames = terragrunt output -json all_functionapp_names | ConvertFrom-Json          
      Write-Output -InputObject "INFO: Loop over Function Apps"
      $jobs = $appNames | ForEach-Object -Parallel {          
          $name = $_          
          try              
          {          
              Write-Output -InputObject "INFO: $name`: start slot"        
              az functionapp start --resource-group $(ResourceGroup) --name "$name" --slot Stage --verbose
              Write-Output -InputObject "INFO: $name`: deploy into slot"        
              az functionapp deploy --resource-group $(ResourceGroup) --name "$name" --slot Stage --src-path "$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/drop/MyCodePackage.zip" --type zip --verbose
              Write-Output -InputObject "INFO: $name`: deploy app settings"          
              az functionapp config appsettings set --resource-group $(ResourceGroup) --name "$name" --slot Stage --settings "@$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/appsettings.json" --verbose
              Write-Output -InputObject "INFO: $name`: swap slot with production"          
              az functionapp deployment slot swap --resource-group $(ResourceGroup) --name "$name" --slot Stage --action swap --verbose
          }
          catch
          {
              Write-Output -InputObject "ERROR: $name`: An error occured during deployment"
              Write-Output -InputObject ($_.Exception | Format-List -Force)
          }
          finally              
          {
            try
            {
                Write-Output -InputObject "INFO: $name`: stop slot"          
                az functionapp stop --resource-group $(ResourceGroup) --name "$name" --slot Stage --verbose
            }
            catch
            {
                Write-Output -InputObject "ERROR: $name`: could not stop slot"
            }
          }          
      } -AsJob
                          
      [int]$pollingInterval = 10          
      [int]$elapsedSeconds = 0          
      while ($jobs.State -eq "Running") {          
          $jobs.ChildJobs | ForEach-Object {          
              Write-Output -InputObject "---------------------------------"          
              Write-Output -InputObject "INFO: $($_.Name) output [$($elapsedSeconds)s]"          
              Write-Output -InputObject "---------------------------------"          
              $_ | Receive-Job          
              Write-Output -InputObject "---------------------------------"          
              Write-Output -InputObject ""          
          }          
          $elapsedSeconds += $pollingInterval          
          [Threading.Thread]::Sleep($pollingInterval * 1000)          
      }          
      $jobs.ChildJobs | Where-Object { $_.JobStateInfo.State -eq "Failed" } | ForEach-Object {          
          Write-Output -InputObject "ERROR: At least one of the deployments failed with the following reason:"          
          Write-Output -InputObject $_.JobStateInfo.Reason          
      }
                          
      if ($jobs.State -eq "Failed")          
      {          
          exit 1          
      }          
      else          
      {          
          exit 0          
      }
    powerShellErrorActionPreference: 'continue'
    workingDirectory: './infrastructure/environments/$(TerraFormEnvironmentName)'
```

### Edit 1

To get all output from `ChildJobs` I had to alter the code like so:

```
      [int]$pollingInterval = 10          
      [int]$elapsedSeconds = 0          
      $lastResultsRead = false
      while ($jobs.State -eq "Running" -or !$lastResultsRead)
      {          
          $lastResultsRead = $jobs.State -ne "Running"
          $jobs.ChildJobs | ForEach-Object {          
              Write-Output -InputObject "---------------------------------"          
              Write-Output -InputObject "INFO: $($_.Name) output [$($elapsedSeconds)s]"          
              Write-Output -InputObject "---------------------------------"          
              $_ | Receive-Job          
              Write-Output -InputObject "---------------------------------"          
              Write-Output -InputObject ""          
          }          
          $elapsedSeconds += $pollingInterval          
          if (!$lastResultsRead)
          {
              [Threading.Thread]::Sleep($pollingInterval * 1000)
          }
```

Hope this helps everyone that wants to achieve something similar.

Comment: Good work with the script. I have two questions? Did you try to run it locally? DId you consider splitting runs to seprate job, so each job handle one function?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej Thanks. Yes, in fact I developed the script locally first. I just took the current version and ran it locally again. Still works as expected. No error. How would splitting it into separate jobs help my situation? Is there any advantage of multiple jobs over one job with multiple child jobs when we're talking about roughly 2-6 parallel executions?

Comment: Seprate jobs, means in fact seprate machine - it could help if there is strange interaction between azure cli calls - which should not happen, but we are where we are.

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej As I tried to describe in my post, this is not possible. My preferred way of implementation would've been to create a YAML array with each of the deployments as a separate entry. But for this Azure Pipelines requires to know the elements up-front. There is no way to create a YAML array dynamically. Hence separate jobs in the pipeline are not possible. Also, the deployment itself works fine right now. It's simply the reporting of Azure CLI in combination with how the Azure CLI task handles StdErr output that leads to the described problem.

Comment: Curious: What version of PowerShell Core is installed on the agent?  I believe `-Parallel` was added in PowerShell 7.0 Preview 3 (and higher).

Comment: According to the Microsoft documentation: 7.1.4
See: https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2004-README.md#powershell-tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that the mystery is solved.

### TLDR;

If you want proper error handling, remove the `--verbose` from all Azure CLI calls as the verbose output is **always** written to StdErr even when setting the environment variable `AZURE_CORE_ONLY_SHOW_ERRORS`.

### Explanation

I stumbled over the solution by adding an unrelated functionality to this script and noticed that in certain situations the last output of the `ChildJobs` is not being collected. I initially took that for a quirk of the Azure DevOps task but discovered that this also happens when I debug the output locally in VSCode.

That led me to add another condition for the `while` loop that would ensure to give me the final output. I'll update the script in my initial post accordingly. Finally equipped with the whole picture of what is going on in the `ChildJobs` I set up a separate test pipeline where I would run different test cases to find the culprit. Soon enough I noticed that taking away `--verbose` prevents the task from failing. This happened with `AZURE_CORE_ONLY_SHOW_ERRORS` set or not. So I gave the `--only-show-errors` option a go, which should have the same result as the environment variable though only on a single Azure CLI call. Due to the full output now at my disposal I could finally see the message that `--verbose` and `--only-show-errors` can't be used in conjunction. That settled it. `--verbose` had to go. All it adds is the information of how long the command ran anyway. I think we can do without it.

On an additional side-note: at the same time I discovered that `ForEach-Object -Parallel {} -AsJob` is making heavy use of PowerShell runspaces. That means that it cannot be debugged from within VSCode in the typical way. I found a video that might help in situations like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O-dksknPQBw

I hope this answer helps others that stumble over the same strange behavior. Happy coding.